# nginx rewrite code for ZenPHOTO 1.4.5

Tags: nginx

I have the following Apache rewrite rule for my ZenPHOTO 1.4.5 gallery:

```
'<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteBase /  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^.*/?$    index.php [L,QSA]  
</IfModule>`
```

and I need to be able to use it with Nginx.

Can anyone help me convert it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of updating the question with your solution, answer your own question and accept the answer so the question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, i am using the following rules it works for me.

```
location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png) {
  try_files $uri @img_proxy;
}
location @img_proxy {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1;
}
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri;
}
```

Note: It works for latest [ZenPHOTO 1.4.5](http://www.zenphoto.org/news/zenphoto-1.4.5) version and i didn't check old versions.